# Need to create a CenterIT function using input_str and size as arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to write a CenterIT(input_str, size) function with the first argument being a string and the second being an integer to return a string with its length being equal to size with input_str in the center, if possible. If size is less than the length of input_str, return input_str unchanged.

```
def centerit(input_str, size):
    if size <= len(input_str):
        return input_str
    for x in range((size - len(input_str))/2):
        input_str = " " + input_str + " "
    if len(input_str) == size:
        return input_str
    return input_str + " "
```

Edit: I was able to come up with this with other help, how do I call my function though?

Comment: This looks like homework Taylor... any how.. `size = return len(raw_input)` is not valid. `return len(raw_input)` is. if you set it inside the function is not going to "carry out" because python sends simple types by value not reference. Give us the rest of the problem so we can make heads and tails of what the ridiculous requirements you CS teacher is trying to make you do.

Comment: you have to use `raw_input` before you call `CenterIT` so `raw_input` shouldn't be part of  `CenterIT`

Comment: That is the whole problem. He is a very vague teacher. I was mainly hoping you all could clarify the problem, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the documentation that can help you:
- If you want to get something from user just use [input](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) function.
- That's how you create a [function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) which you created already (there are example in there for calling it.)
All of your answers are in those documents.